# How to generate iPhone simulator build or .zip file for submit in Facebook for review in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ios-simulator

I submit my_app.ipa file to Facebook but its rejected by Facebook.
And send me this message "Notes from our review team
iPhone
Can you please resubmit for review providing a simulator build of your iOS app, and not an .ipa file? I'm reviewing your submission in an iOS simulator that needs your app to be built following these instructions: **(.zip) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review**"
But i was enable to create .zip file of simulator build. and i tried below  steps also

```
Step 1: open finder and press option+ shift+g
Step 2: paste "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"
Step 3: select my_app-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh some this like this folder
Step 4: my_app-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh >>Build >>Products>>Debug-iphonesimulator
Step 5: I see 2 file one is my_app(icon like rounder and 1 cross line ) and 2nd file is my_app.app.dsym
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In my case ,i use the below command to build zip file
`ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc —-keepParent “source" "destination"`

where `source` is `/Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourapp.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yourapp.app`

and destination is where you save the .zip file.

[image]

Comment: can i use this below steps?
The easiest way I've found to make this work is to:

Build and run the app for the simulator in xcode.
Go to Products in the left-hand nav in Xcode and control-click (right-click) on YourApp.app and Select Show In Finder. (This is the .app you want to use)
If you want a .zip just control-click (right-click) on the app and Select "Compress YourApp.app"

Comment: i dont think so ,that compress the same way it does with command,the command i mentioned is straight forward use it.I used it and approved my app from Facebook ppl

Comment: but i got an error like this "ditto: Can't archive multiple sources
Usage: ditto [ <options> ] src [ ... src ] dst"

Comment: @Stela I had this error also. I realized it's because my app name has a space in it. To work around this, I first executed the command `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` which displayed `/some/long/path/to/my appname.app`.  Then I added single quotes around that result when I executed `ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent '/some/long/path/to/my appname.app' outputfile.zip` and it worked.

Comment: @RobP your answer was what got it to work for me. I had spaces in my app name too, and that was the problem. But, when I copy and pasted your first command, it, for some reason, was randomly adding a space in iphonesimulator. So, it was in my terminal as iphon esimulator, and I had to correct that to get it working.

Comment: For those of you having issues, I've found that the commands posted aren't charactarized well. Try this `ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent 'source_path' destination_path`

Answer (score 7):

I used below command and its working for me.

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourapp.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yourapp.app  /Users/mac/Desktop/yourapp.zip
```

You can use your destination path instead of  **/Users/mac/Desktop/yourapp.zip**.

Answer (score 6):

for those of you getting the error ""ditto: Can't archive multiple sources":

use --keepParent with two dashes in front of it

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc —-keepParent “source" "destination"
```

Comment: this wasn't my issue at all, I already had the two dashes. See my comment under muku's answer, the same ditto error message will result if your app's name has an internal space.

Comment: Also if you copied over the command from elsewhere there are chances they are mal characterized. I had the issue and took ages for me to find out what the issue was.

Answer (score 3):

1. Based on [Facebook developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced/#sim_build), you just need the
   command below (remember to change your destination path).

   ```
   ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` path/to/YourApp.zip
   ```

---

2. To verify your build, install [ios-sim](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-sim?fbclid=IwAR1m9Xtuf_rvcUFDkIt_oyKQZN08ztLKuHoX7S40M5isuHLIY980b3QPVb8) package and run the command below (d is devicetypeid).

   ```
   ios-sim launch /path/to/your-app.app -d iPhone-X
   ```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. I tried running `ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc —-keepParent “source" "destination"` and received "ditto: Can't archive multiple sources" despite their being no spaces in my source path.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any of this strange ditto stuff.

You can simply zip the app up and upload it. I've had several apps approved this way.

App is usually located:
`/Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourapp.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yourapp.app`

Comment: Only .app file? Nothing more?

Answer (score 1):

Use below command. It will work. Change below path for your app file.

ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent '/some/long/path/to/my appname.app' /Desktop/outputfile.zip

to find your app file path on "/Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourapp.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yourapp.app"

Answer (score 0):

1. Step: Run App in Simulator
   Run your app in your Xcode iPhone 5 simulator. This automatically creates a simulator build in Xcode's DerivedData cache.
2. Step: ZIP Simulator Build
   Zip the simulator build via the following command:

ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` path/to/YourApp.zip

3. Step: Verify Build
   You can verify the simulator build by using the ios-sim utility Command-line App Launcher for Simulator. Once installed run:

ios-sim launch /path/to/your-app.app

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate the build for a flutter project, follow these steps: -

1. Open Terminal and type `open -a Simulator`
2. Run your Flutter project
3. Once the app is running, terminate the debugging session and go to the following path: `<project_root>/build/ios/iphonesimulator`. Here you will find the `*.app` file.
4. Open the terminal again and write `ios-sim launch`  and then drag and drop the `*.app` file in the same terminal.

That's it. You have the simulator build ready for Facebook. Just right-click the `.app` file and selected the option to `Compress "*.app"`.