# How to create a simulator build file

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mobile

I am trying to create simulator build and submit to Facebook for App Review.Can anyone tell me how to create simulator build and submit to Facebook?

Comment: Don't they tell you in the documentation or from where they request this? I normally do all my builds through jenkins so have some command line options that might help. I'll have a look

Comment: Check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate iPhone simulator build or .zip file for submit in Facebook for review in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933082/how-to-generate-iphone-simulator-build-or-zip-file-for-submit-in-facebook-for-r)